# Catalog Price Rule for Cross-sell product

Tags: discount, cross-sells

I'm using Magento 1.9 and I'd like to do the following.

If the cart is a subtotal bigger than X amount, I'd like to discount a cross-selling item (or only show an item at a certain price). Else still show the cross-selling item but not discounted.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Shopping Cart Rule` in `Conditions` add `subtotal > x`.

Then in `Actions` set `Apply only apply on items matching` to your cross-sell item.

The problem with this is that it will only be shown when added to the cart.

You could also create a bundle make it easier to purchase such products.